# Comparison with Borel algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ generated by the intervals $[n, n+1]$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Can someone explain to me the concept of spanning a $\sigma$-algebra? And can someone explain the difference between $\mathcal{F}$ and the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Do you have a definition of "spanning a $\sigma$-algebra"? Perhaps you meant to say "generated"? Including this in your question would help tremendously.

Comment: @Satana exactly thats the word, also i need to understand that further more

Comment: This is the type or question you would be asked to get you to think about the definitions.  So include in the question what you know.

Answer (score 0):

Using the popular definition of Borel $\sigma$-algebra, i.e the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all the closed (equivalently all the open) subsets of $\mathbb R$, one can easliy see that $\mathcal F$ is contained in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ because $\mathcal F$ is generated by some closed intervals.

Now coming to the question whether these two are same or distinct. To generate a $\sigma$-algebra out of a family of subsets, one has to collect all the complements of these sets, then collect all the countable intersections and their countable unions and so on. It is easily seen that Borel $\sigma$-algebra contains all the singleton sets of $\mathbb R$, while the only singletons you can obtain performing above given set operations on the family $\{[n,n+1]~:~n\in \mathbb Z\}$ in $\mathcal F$ are positive integers. No matter how many repetitions of these allowed set operations are performed, one cannot obtain singleton sets other than the ones containing positive integer. Hence, these two sigma algebras are distinct.

Comment: you didnt explain the concept of "generated", you said F is contained in the borel sigma-algebra because F is generated by some closed intervals, isnt borel also generated by closed intervals over R?

Comment: Sigma algebra generated by a family of subsets is defined as the smallest sigma algebra containing those subsets. In other words it is the intersection of all the sigma algebras containing those subsets.